# Having an unsual amount of trouble adjusting widths of items in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make a four column section that grows and shrinks without wrapping the content blocks. The articles that are within the sections don't seem to be responding whenever I adjust the widths, and I am not sure why. I've tried a number of different solution (no-wrap, min-width, etc.), but I can't seem to get the article width smaller than width: 5%, which when you look at the article, visually it's definitely not 5%. What's going on here? In the sample below, I've commented out different aspects of the CSS that I've tried.

```
<button onclick="openSection()">LEARN MORE</button>
    <div id="section1">
      <h1>Four Wonderful Things About My Item</h1>
      <section>
        <article>
          <h2>1</h2>
          <p class="fade-in">All about item 1.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="fade-in">
          <h2>2</h2>
          <p>What a great thing that item 2 is.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="fade-in">
          <h2>3</h2>
          <p>But let's not forget about item 3.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="fade-in">
          <h2>4</h2>
          <p>Item 4 is something else.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
    </div>

#section1 {
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    /* width: 85%;
    margin: 6rem auto; */
}

#section1 section {
    background-color: peru;
    color: black;
    /* display: none; */
    /* padding: 0;
    margin: 0; */
    align-items: stretch;
    /* display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex; */
    display: flex;
    /* -webkit-flex-flow: nowrap; */
    /* -webkit-flex-flow: wrap; */
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#section1 article {
    /* background: white; */
    /* padding: .5rem; */
    /* margin: .5rem; */
    /* min-height: 300px; */
    /* min-width: 0; */
    /* padding: 0; */
    /* justify-content: space-between; */
    min-width: 0;
    /*the flex feature*/
    /* max-width: 5%; */
    background: tomato;
    color: white;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    /* font-size: 3rem; */
    /* text-align: center; */
    margin: .5rem;
    /* flex: 1 1 auto; */
    /* flex: 1 1 1 1; */
    /* outline: 1px solid blue; */
}
```

Comment: I'm not having trouble resizing anything here, could you clarify exactly what it is you can't resize?

Comment: Sure. I want the <article> to get narrower as the screen width gets smaller. Right now, it stays the same size until it bumps to the next line.